# Where can I save private key used in java code

Tags: java, certificate, datasource, keystore, private-key

I'm developing web application on Java, spring, JDBC, which is deployed on Tomcat 7. 
I'm making encryption/decryption of a data-source password using private key.

Now I have this private key hard coded in Java code. But **I have to save private key in more secured place**. 
How can I do this?

Is it a good idea to generate certificate (key-store, key-pair), install it on tomcat and retrieve this data from java code?

Comment: Use a keystore. You can put a password on the private key and a separate password on the keystore file. Check my answer on this question for some code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272842/open-x509-certificate-store-from-java-apis/14273320#14273320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a problem you cannot easily solve. If you store your key in a keystore you will need a key to access the keystore and where do you store this?

If this is really a high security application the only way is to use a dedicated hardware security box for doing the decryption.

Comment: What do you mean in using a dedicated hardware security box? Should I save my keystore in dedicated secured storage?

Comment: For high security yes, but most probably your application does not need that level of security because then one would rather encrypt the sensitive data already in the database.